# ConstraintLayout Resize views for smaller Screens

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

What is the best way of supporting different screen sizes when using a constrainLayout?

**The problem:**

When I change the device to any device with a screen size of less than 4.7" the button at the bottom tends to go below the bottom edge of the screen. I have anchored the button and I thought that all the views will be shrunk to accommodate the rest.

**My code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:adjustViewBounds="false"
      android:cropToPadding="false"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:3"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/maziwapp_logo"
      />
  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"
      />
  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp"
      />
  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp"
      />
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/emailTxt"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:background="@drawable/edittext_outline"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
      android:hint="Email"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingStart="10dp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:typeface="serif"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
      tools:text="Email"
      />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/passwordTxt"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
      android:background="@drawable/edittext_outline"
      android:hint="Password"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingStart="10dp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/emailTxt"
      tools:text="Password"
      />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:text="I forgot my password?"
      android:textColor="@color/colorFont1"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/passwordTxt"
      />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
      android:background="@drawable/login_button"
      android:text="Login"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
      tools:textAllCaps="false"
      />

  <view
      android:id="@+id/view2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="2dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
      />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:background="@drawable/create_account_button"
      android:text="Create New Account"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
      tools:textAllCaps="false"
      />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Captures**:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Everything seems ok. What are you trying to do?

Comment: When I change the device to any device with a screen size of less than 4.7" the button at the bottom tends to go below the bottom edge of the screen. I have anchored the button and I thought that all the views will be shrunk to accommodate the rest.

Comment: Posts the xml please

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nathanmkaya/b997963e710663f32c4fe0a98196d8b2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that all the views will be shrunk to accommodate the rest.

No. You have to design it so that it `supports a certain minimum screen size`.
And this is not specific only to `ConstraintLayout`, it will happen with `RelativeLayout` or any other layout.

Please see [supporting different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html).

In your case you can use a [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html), so that the content will scroll when it exceed the size of the screen.

Comment: There must be a way to support it with the one layout file. Use scroll views should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into this *I simply wrap my ConstraintLayout in a ScrollView*. 
Most designs are made for one screen size in mind, I don't think your minimum screen size should need to be so large.

Hope this helps.