# Android studio ConstraintLayout resizing problem

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

I'm pretty new in Android Studio and I'm facing a problem with ConstraintLayout. Namely, I'm trying to make my app fully responsive and while the width of my components perfectly adjusts to any screen size, I have no clue how to make the height to adjust the same way. Instead, my layout goes vertically off the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.skorupinski.lunchtime.LoginActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="254dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_form"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_arrow3"
            android:contentDescription="back_arrow"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.005"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.013" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="133dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="133dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.593" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="478dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/info_box"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.779" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.577" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_input_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font"
            android:text="E-mail"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_input"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/password_input_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font"
            android:text="Hasło"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/password_input"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.136"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_gradient_button"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font"
            android:text="Zaloguj się"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.341" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I would like the layout to fit perfectly any screen size.

Comment: Here a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264812/constraintlayout-resize-views-for-smaller-screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your constraints weren't connected properly with the views in your xml file.

Try this, I have modified your xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="254dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_form"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
            android:contentDescription="back_arrow"
            android:tint="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.005"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.013" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.593" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="478dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/info_box"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_input" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_input_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="E-mail"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_input"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/password_input_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hasło"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/password_input"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.136"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
            android:text="Zaloguj się"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password_input"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/password_input"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_input" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use a ScrollView element wich contains your ConstraintLayout elements, I recommend to use a single ConstraintLayout at least it's necessary. I used [this](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) when I first started using ConstraintLayout, it was very helpful.